# Wien bridge using single potentiometer

Tags: potentiometer

I'm making a function generator which works in the audio range for a college project. I'm not allowed to use microcontrollers or any digital chips. So I'm using a Wien Bridge oscillator with a pot to generate variable sine wave. It is followed by a Schmitt trigger to generate square waves and finally an integrator to get triangle wave. I found this schematic on the web for the Wein bridge:

[image: Schematic]

Could you replace the two variable 100k pots by a single pot? If not, is it possible to somehow mechanically (or electrically) gang the two different 100k pots? I'm trying to avoid using a single double-ganged-potentiometer to save cost.

I would like my final design to have only two pots. One for frequency and one for amplitude.

Comment: Can you use a 555 timer?

Comment: yeah that was my first choice.i can easily get a square or triangle wave with 555.the main problem is with sine wave.i would need to filter the harmonics out of a square wave.that is difficult since i need variable frequency

Comment: OK,  I posted this the other day.  It needs a dual power supply, but it has much better gain control than your circuit. https://www.dropbox.com/s/lmso5zx69g2l1lc/DSCF0047.JPG

Comment: Thanks.But this would still need two pots I guess?Looks like i have to use a ganged pot.

Comment: Or you could do like HP did in their venerable 204 series of oscillators and use a ganged variable capacitor.

Comment: @Spehro Pefhany I've got several tubes of left over XR2206 IC's, maybe I can sell them to undergrads. :^)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you forced to use the WIEN oscillator (named after Max WIEN) topology ?
There are other oscillator types with single-element control - however with two operational amplifiers.

Here is a corresponding link:
http://m.eet.com/media/1143038/17995-82202di.pdf

I like to mention that for frequency tuning you only have to tune one single grounded resistor. More than that, the quality of the output signal (THD) - for most applications - will be sufficient, even without additional amplitude control mechanism.

**EDIT:** To all who also are interested in the update of the referenced paper:
Try this link (I hope it works) and search for "A novel harmonic Oscillator: GIC Resonator" :
https://www.researchgate.net/profile/Lutz_Von_Wangenheim/publications

Comment: No.Any oscillator with variable sine frequency will do .Could you name or post a few alternatives

Comment: I have a pdf doc on my hard disc - but I don´t know how to submit. Any advice?

Comment: I don't know.i'm new here.You could mail me at kishoresaldanha@gmail.com .

Comment: I have updated my answer above with a link to a corresponding article. However, I have an updated version which I will send to you via mail, OK?

Answer (score 0):

Well you could probably rig something up to turn both pots at the same time.  But I think a dual ganged pot will be cheaper.  I've used a Bourns dual ganged pot ~$5.
http://octopart.com/partsearch#!?q=91a2ab28b
Not the first hit.

You can also use a dual switch.  Or maybe a digital pot?